# Create EC2 instance in stopped state through api by aws-sdk in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-js

I need to create new EC2 instance in stopped state using aws-sdk in nodejs. Currently I use `runInstances` method to create new EC2 instances. But these instances are created in running state by default.
I haven't find any parameter yet by which I can define state while creating new EC2 instance.

The object which I pass to the method `runInstances` is

```
{
        ImageId: "ami-0dd2fbaxxxxx",
        InstanceType: "t3a.xlarge",
        KeyName: "xxxxx",
        MaxCount: 1,
        MinCount: 1,
        SecurityGroupIds: ['sg-xxx', 'sg-xxx'],
        CreditSpecification: {
            CpuCredits: 'standard'
        },
        TagSpecifications: [
            {
                ResourceType: "instance",
                Tags: [
                    {
                        Key: "xxx",
                        Value: "xxx"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```